# Visible binding not working (knockout js)

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

net MVC usig knockout js to bind data.
But I am stuck on this below problem.
I am display message if ajax result return true but it does not work
Here below is the code. Please help me

```js
 self.Message = ko.observable(false);      

          $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("SaveAccount", "Accounts")',
                cache: false,
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: jsonData,
                success: function (result) {
                    //ShowToastMessage("This is message", "This is title");
                    self.DealerID(result.DealerId);
                    self.Message = ko.observable(result.Message); //result.Message = true   
                    //self.Message(result.Message);
                    //window.location.href = result.url;
                },
                error: function (errorThrown) {
                }
            });
```

```html
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" id="Success-alert" data-bind="visible: Message">
   <label>Success! Account has been saved successfully</label>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to update your observable instead of overriding it: `self.Message(result.Message); //result.Message = true `

Comment: I try it bro but it does't work

Comment: Are you sure that you have a boolean value in `result.Message` and not the string `"true"`? Try it with `self.Message(result.Message == "true");`

Comment: yeah sure it reurn true